What approach should I take to testing an implied claim for something already answered?
In a recent post I asked the question are one in four victims of intimate partner homicides in australia male.
When I originally posted the question I assumed the perpertators were female, this was based on the source of the claim and a simple calculation I did where I assumed to apply the standard rate of homosexual relationships in the population.
After some thinking I realised my assumptions and the implication that these murders are committed by females may be wrong.
I would like to clarify this point, should I update the original question, ask another but specifically asking about the implication or should I find another post with a direct claims.
My question would be something like, are the people who commit intimate partner homocide against men women?  or something like that.

I think you should ask a second question.
But, we need a notable claim. If it is just your curiosity, it is off-topic here. We need to find a widely-believed claim that someone is making.
